# Best Python framework for embedded system ( memory 64MB, HD 256MB)

Tags: python, django, cherrypy

I have one doubt. I need to write site on embedded system ( memory 64MB, HD 256MB ), I already have Python there and SQLite. I thought to use Django for this, but I heard that Django uses memory a lot. What framework is the best choice for me ( I need to have session and access to sqlite )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need only simple features, the embedded http server of python [simplehttpserver](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) it a good choice.

If you need more advanced features, it seems that [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) is a serious candidate as an embedded WebServer as it is able [to run on an android platform](http://www.defuze.org/archives/228-running-cherrypy-on-android-with-sl4a.html).